# Unable to Modify the Opportunity Close Dialog in 2019 Release Wave 2 of Microsoft Dynamics CRM 365

Tags: dynamics-crm

I am trying to use the new feature that is included in 2019 Release Wave 2 of Microsoft Dynamics CRM 365 that allows the Opportunity Close dialog box to be modified.

I followed all the instructions to modify this dialog, however whatever I try doesn't work.

I made sure the following settings where present:

1. Went into the Power Platform Admin Center and made sure that my instance was upgraded to the October 2019 Release Wave 2.
2. In my instance I went into Settings > Administration > System Settings > and under the tab "Sales" made sure "Customize close opportunity form" is set to "Yes".
3. I then created a new text field for Opportunity Close and added it to both the quick form and main form.
4. I published all my changes.
5. When I go to an Opportunity and click on "Close as Lost" I do not see my new field on the form.

Has anyone else encountered issues where their changes did not appear in the Opportunity Closed form? If so what was the cause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using new UI and not the classic one.
Becuase Opportunity close quick creat form will work only in new UI. I just tried it on one of my system and it works. But when  I try same on classic it won't

Note I added field Priority on quick create form

[image]

But now when I try this on Classic it does not work

[image]

Comment: Thanks AnkUser. I will try this and let you know.

Comment: Hi AnkUser, We tried this in Unified Interface and it didn't work. We then opened a support ticket with Microsoft. They confirmed that it must be in UIC for this to work. We also had another issue that Microsoft had to run a mitigation script for. This script sets two switches associated with the Close as Won and Close as Lost button to true. They are "IsVisibleInMobileClient" and "IsVisibleInMobile". Apparently other clients have had issues with these switches as well. So in short you are correct. It must be in UCI.